# How to Create a Xamarin Cross-Platform App with No UI?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin

Which template/options should I use to create a Xamarin based cross-platform application with no UI and without the overhead of UI functionality in the final code?

Comment: Do you mean without Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: With no UI at all, like a service, but an app.

Comment: There is no such animal in a x-plat style as there is no equal on all platforms. i.e. On iOS you would have to jail-break the device to run a "service".

Comment: Agreed, no such thing. In Android, there are apps and there are services. You can create a service for Android (no idea how that works in iOS) and start here: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/service/create_a_simple_service/

What @SushiHangover said sounds right - you'd have to jail break iOS to do this at all.